# C# - Can I use an array initializer to build one byte array out of another?

Tags: c#, byte, arrays, array-initialization

I'd like to use an array initializer to build one byte array out of another byte array as well as some other bytes that form a header/trailer. Basically, I'd like to do something like this:

```
byte[] DecorateByteArray(byte[] payload)
{
    return new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, payload.GetBytes(), 3, 4, 5};
}
```

`GetBytes()` above is fictional, unfortunately.

Is there any nice/elegant way to do this? I solved this by using a `BinaryWriter` to write everything to a `MemoryStream`, and then converting this into a byte array with `MemoryStream.ToArray()`, but it feels kind of clunky.

Comment: It's annoying because I wan't to close this [as a dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616371/insert-a-byte-array-into-another-byte-array-at-a-specific-position-with-c-sharp)... but your specific wording kind of makes it immune to that.... so to answer your annoying wording: NO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest you could get would be:

```
byte[] DecorateByteArray(byte[] payload) =>
    new byte[] { 0, 1, 2 } 
       .Concat(payload)
       .Concat(new byte[] { 3, 4, 5 })
       .ToArray();
```

That would be pretty inefficient though. You'd be better off doing something like:

```
static T[] ConcatArrays<T>(params T[][] arrays)
{
    int length = arrays.Sum(a => a.Length);
    T[] ret = new T[length];
    int offset = 0;
    foreach (T[] array in arrays)
    {
        Array.Copy(array, 0, ret, offset, array.Length);
        offset += array.Length;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

(Consider using `Buffer.BlockCopy` too, where appropriate.)

Then call it with:

```
var array = ConcatArrays(new byte[] { 0, 1, 2 }, payload, new byte[] { 3, 4, 5 });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new collection that is a `List<byte>`, but that has an overload of `Add` that adds a whole array of bytes:

```
public class ByteCollection: List<byte>
{
    public void Add(IEnumerable<byte> bytes)
    {
        AddRange(bytes);
    }
}
```

This then lets you use the collection initializer for this type to supply either a single byte or a sequence of bytes, which you can then turn back into an array if you need an array:

```
byte[] DecorateByteArray(byte[] payload)
{
    return new ByteCollection() { 0, 1, 2, payload, 3, 4, 5 }.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I didn't know you can override add so you can initialize a collection damn!

Comment: @johnny5 I didn't override it.  I overloaded it.  Big difference.  Add is `sealed`, and so cannot be overridden.

Comment: I meant overload, didn't have my coffee this morning

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to break out each into parts and then concat them

```
byte[] DecorateByteArray(byte[] payload)
{  
    return new byte[] { 0, 1, 2}
        .Concat(payload.GetBytes())
        .Concat(new byte[] { 3, 4, 5});
}
```