# Send all bytes from richTextBox

Tags: c#, arrays, richtextbox

I have a richTextBox and byte array.

```
byte[] message = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(richTextBox1.Text);

byte[] bytesToSend = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, (MESSAGE SHOULD BE HERE), 0x00 };
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert a byte array into another byte array at a specific position with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616371/insert-a-byte-array-into-another-byte-array-at-a-specific-position-with-c-sharp)

Comment: note: you should almost never use `Encoding.Default` - it is very badly named in terms of what it actually means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
    static byte[] SomeMethod(string value, Encoding encoding)
    {
        // create an array with the space needed for the value and the zeros
        var bytes = new byte[encoding.GetByteCount(value) + 9];
        // encode the data into the array starting at position 8
        encoding.GetBytes(value, 0, value.Length, bytes, 8);
        // and we're done
        return bytes;
    }
    var bytesToSend = SomeMethod(richTextBox1.Text, Encoding.Default);
    // (but probably not Encoding.Default - that is almost always wrong)
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if i want to send some different bytes instead of zeros?

Comment: @tony then ... overwrite the bytes you want to change?

Comment: `byte[] bytesToSend = new byte[] { 0x08, 0x08, 0xAB, 0xFE, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, (MESSAGE SHOULD BE HERE), 0x00 }`

Comment: @tony you could overwrite them manually one-by-one, or you could create a static byte[] field that is those bytes and use memory-copy... frankly, in this case I'd probably just do it manually: `bytes[0] = bytes[1] = 0x08; bytes[2] = 0xAB; bytes[3] = 0xFE;` ?